# Integrating Twilio Android SDK into All Native Dialer/Phone Call UIs

Tags: java, android, sip, twilio

Hoping someone more familiar than I with the Android SDK can offer some insight here.

In short, I downloaded Twilio's Client SDK for Android, which comes with bare-bones sample app that lets you make and receive voice calls -- all from within that same app.

I'd like to take this a step further, and would appreciate it if someone could point me in the direction of what classes I need to implement or (ideally) already-existing open source projects that do something similar.

Basically, I want to be able to configure Twilio client accounts akin to how you can configure SIP connections. To make a call via Twilio, I want to be able to use the normal phone-dialing UI, so that when I go to place an outgoing call, I can choose what connection/protocol I want to use (i.e. GSM vs. Twilio using GSM data or WiFi), but otherwise the in-call UI is identical.

I simply want to have to code a wrapper for the Twilio SDK to make it a drop-in replacement service provider for users to choose on the fly.

In other words, I don't want to have to code:

- Any sort of UI for placing a call, receiving a call, or UI to manage an in-progress call. (However I expect to need to code handlers for when these various actions are selected by the user.)
- Adding calls to the call log or maintaining a separate one.
- A custom dialer.

Is this possible at all? If so, how?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Hi mikev,This is priyank,i am also working on android twilio sdk and also wanted to implement thing like you,in my case i have to show custom dial pad along with my screen because right now i am not able to handle voice menu events like if i am using native dialer its not going to work with me so you have any idea how can i do like this,i want it like IVR if its say me like press one to go enter so how can i add this event in dial pad,really not getting help from anywhere,hope you have some suggestion Thanks,waiting for reply.